# Autocomplete while compiling a file with c++ is gone

Tags: 13.04, compiling, c++, auto-completion

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and have been programming mostly in C++. I use vim editor and `c++` command to compile my .cpp file. What I have noticed is after typing `c++` and pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, an autocomplete was expected for the files present in the current directory, but it gives no result. It was fine before, and I have become used to the `c++` command for compiling my files.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `.bashrc`:

```
complete -f c++
```